# Power Query - How to convert all columns to type TEXT

Tags: powerquery

How can i convert all columns in a table to type TEXT (where the number of columns on refresh will change every time therefore this has to apply for all columns and i cannot select the columns manually)

I have tried answers from ChatGPT but without any luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding a new step similar to:

```
Table.TransformColumnTypes(
 Source,
 List.Transform(
   Table.ColumnNames(Source),
   each {_, type text}
 )
)
```